# Logitech Options not saving preferences

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, logitech-keyboard

I recently came across a most annoying issue where my [Logitech Options](https://blog.logitech.com/2016/12/14/logitech-options-makes-mice-keyboards-even-powerful/) application is not saving my preferences that are made in the application. I use this application to change settings for my  Logitech K400 keyboard. One of the options is to use Fkeys as normal keys (instead of using a modifier key with the Fkey), as well as options to disable pinch zooming on the trackpad.

While troubleshooting, I noticed that the functions that I want actually work when the app is open, but not after a reboot or logoff/logon, so my current assumption here is that the software needs to be running in order for these changes to work. I had assumed in the past that these values were written to a reg file, as I never saw Logitech Options running in my task manager.

I have tried also running the application as admin without seeing any difference. The settings are not saved.

So while a current workaround is to simply place a shortcut for Logitech Options in my startup folder, I want to know if there is a problem with how this application works? Does Logitech Options actually need to be running for my preferences to be active? It may be that I need the daemon to be running (not the interface where I choose the options). If this is the case, how do I get the daemon to launch at startup without opening the preferences application?

```
Logitech Software Version: 8.20.329
Logitech Firmware Version: 063.002.00016
OS Version: Windows 10 Pro 20H2
OS build 19042.985
```

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution. The Logitech Options runs a daemon that runs in the background which needs to be running in order for the preferences to be in effect. To make sure this is running at startup I first needed to locate the daemon program.

To do this, first open the Logitech Options program to ensure the daemon is running. You can close Logitech Option immediately, as we do not need this app open. Next is to [open the Task Manger](https://www.ionos.ca/digitalguide/server/configuration/how-to-open-task-manager/) and then navigate to **LogiOptionsMgr.exe{UNICODE}** and right click the entry and select 'Properties'.

[image]

Once in the Properties window, highlight and copy the directory path where it says 'Location' and paste this in the address bar of Windows Explorer. This will take you to the directory of where **LogiOptionsMgr.exe** is located. The location on my machine is:

```
C:\ProgramData\Logishrd\LogiOptions\Software\Current
```

Next, right click on the **LogiOptionsMgr.exe** and use 'Create Shortcut' and place the newly created shortcut in your Startup Folder. On my machine, I placed the shortcut in two directories:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```

Now whenever your machine restarts, reboots, or logs back on after being logged off, this **LogiOptionsMgr.exe** will load your preferences.

Comment: This is a lifesaver! Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore! Im trying the usual workarounds, but with the recent update it seems Logitech still hasn't figured this out.

Answer (score 1):

I thought i had this issue but it turned out I had "app-specific customizations" overriding my customizations on some apps.